# Plugin missing from organisation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

We have had a plugin registered for a few months. It was referenced by a solutions in two organisations and I could see it in Solution > Components > Plug-in Assemblies in each organisation.

Yesterday I noticed it was not visible in this view. The Plugin Registration Tool shows it still installed.

I unregistered it using the Plugin Registration Tool and then registered it again but it still isn't visible in the solution that references it in either organisation.

We get a "Could not load file or assembly" exception when the plugin is called.

How can I investigate this?

Comment: is it only visibility issue or plugin not working as well?

Comment: Good question. Get "Could not load file or assembly" exception where the plugin should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure why, but it seems to be working again.

I removed all trace of the plugin from both servers and from the orgs and solutions and then added it back and now it seems to be ok.

Is annoying because I don't think I learnt anything and it used a lot of time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Registering a plugin doesn't put it in a solution.  You'll have to add it back manually to whatever solution(s) you want.

Go to `Customizations > Solutions > Open your solution you want the plugin added > Plug-in Assembly > Add Existing`. If the dll doesn't show up there, you either didn't register it at all, or registered it for a different org

Comment: To add to Daryl's comment, 1 common reason you'll find plugins disappearing from solutions is if you completely unregister them (using the plugin registration tool) and re-register them again. If you do this they will fall out of all solutions that reference them within CRM. This happens due the record within the database that references the plugin is being deleted, hence the solution losing it's reference to the plugin. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: In case this is the cause, how would I add them back to the solution?

Comment: @cja - Go to Customizations > Solutions > Open your solution you want the plugin added > Plug-in Assembly > Add Existing.  If the dll doesn't show up there, you either didn't register it at all, or registered it for a different org.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Customization > Customize the System > Plug-in Assemblies`

When you deployed, it might be installed in default solution. You can always add it back to your Solution as @Daryl said.

Comment: It's not visible in Customization > Customize the System > Plug-in Assemblies

Comment: @cja besides, registering the dll, are there steps registered as well?